# React + Spring app issue - AxiosError Could not fetch properties. Object may no longer exist

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple React + Spring app. React part should take 3 parameters from frontend forms (city, state, country) after pressing Submit button, pass them to a backend Spring controller, get a response back and show data values from response on the same page. It works with hardcoded parameters, but there is an issue with more complex React logic.

**Spring controller:**

```
    @CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pollution")
public class PollutionController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PollutionController.class.getName());

    JSONObject response;
    private final PollutionService pollutionService;

    PollutionController(PollutionService pollutionService) {
        this.pollutionService = pollutionService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/current/city")
    public JSONObject getCurrentPollutionDataByCityStateCountry(
            @RequestParam(value = "city") String city,
            @RequestParam(value = "state") String state,
            @RequestParam(value = "country") String country
    ) {
        try {
            response = pollutionService.getCurrentPollutionDataByCityStateCountry(city, state, country);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "/current/city response: {0}", response);
        return response;
    }

}
```

**Response example:**

```
{date=Thu Dec 08 01:15:37 CET 2022, no2=27.76, pm2_5=14.12, pm10=19.07}
```

**React App.js part:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'

import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            responseData:'',
            date: '',
            no2: '',
            pm10: '',
            pm2_5: ''
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick () {
        const city = "New York";
        const state = "New York";
        const country = "US";

        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/pollution/current/city?' +
            'city=' + city +
            '&state='+ state +
            '&country=' + country)
            .then(response => this.setState({responseData: response.data}))
        console.log("responseData.date: " + this.state.responseData.date);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className='button__container'>
                <button className='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
                <p> Date: {this.state.responseData.date}</p>
                <p> no2: {this.state.responseData.no2}</p>
                <p> pm10: {this.state.responseData.pm10}</p>
                <p> pm2_5: {this.state.responseData.pm2_5}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App
```

It works fine, I push Submit button, get response from backend and see results on the same webpage.

[image: Simple valid result]

But it is just a first test stage. As you see, all 3 input parameters are hardcoded here. So I added some logic in App.js file to take parameters from forms:

**Updated App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './App.css'

import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            responseData:'',
            date: '',
            no2: '',
            pm10: '',
            pm2_5: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            country: '',
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    handleClick() {
    console.log("log record 1");
    console.log("city: " + this.state.city);
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/pollution/current/city?' +
            'city=' + this.state.city +
            '&state='+ this.state.state +
            '&country=' + this.state.country)
            .then(response => this.setState({responseData: response.data})).catch((err) => console.error(err));

    console.log("response data: " + this.state.responseData);
    console.log("log record 2");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
                <label>City:
                    <input name="city" type="text" value={this.state.city} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label>State:
                    <input name="state" type="text" value={this.state.state} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label>Country:
                    <input name="country" type="text" value={this.state.country} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </label>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                <br/>
                <p> Date: {this.state.responseData.date}</p>
                <p> no2: {this.state.responseData.no2}</p>
                <p> pm10: {this.state.responseData.pm10}</p>
                <p> pm2_5: {this.state.responseData.pm2_5}</p>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
export default App
```

**And here is an issue** - I put values in the forms, push Submit, request is going to the backend part and it generates response (I can see from backend logs, that it gets parameters and produces a result json), but **I don't see any results on the same webpage**.

**Backend response log:**

```
INFO 77115 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.controller.PollutionController       : /current/city response: {"date":"Fri Dec 09 01:11:49 CET 2022","no2":"19.19","pm10":"45.54","pm2_5":"38.07"}
```

**Result on a webpage:**

[image: No results]

**So my question(s)** - what is wrong with added logic in updated App.js? Why it doesn't render the response data the same way as before? What I miss here?

**UPDATE:**

I've added some loggers in App.js (code above updated with them), and you can see the next result in console:

[image: console screenshot]

There is no data in console for `console.log("response data: " + this.state.responseData);` and there are 2 errors after this. **Why are these errors in my case?**

**UPDATE 2 :**

I've added also exception handling (added to App.js above) and see this in console:

[image]

Comment: Can you please take out <p> tags outside <form> and try again

Comment: @RohitAgarwal could you explain, in what syntax I need to wrap it in this case? If I just take it outside <form></form>, my IDE shows me warning that it is "Unreachable code" .

Comment: If you mean something like 
<div> 
<form onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
*code*
</form>
<p>Date: {this.state.responseData.date}</p>
...
</div>
It also doesn't work (gives the same result).

Comment: Perhaps your form submission refreshes the page. Try with handleClick(e) e.preventDefault();

Comment: @idmitrov you are right! this thing was missed, thank you!

Comment: @idmitrov please feel free to make you comment as an answer on this question and I'll mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background:**
The default behavior of the forms is to refresh the page, which nowadays in modern SPA applications is something that we try to prevent due to many reasons (reset in-memory data/state, cancel ongoing requests, etc...).

**Solution**
So in short whenever there is a form submission then the needed action is to prevent the default behavior.

**In your situation using ReactJS**, the form submission is handled inside the **handleClick** method where the solution would be to handle the event and invoke preventDefault().

e.g.

```
handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // prevent the default behavior
  // The rest of your logic...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one question. I've put in e.preventDefault() in the end of the function after "// The rest of your logic..." and it also works. Does it matter where we put e.preventDefault() inside a function?

Comment: In short, no. More infor about preventDefault here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Some people prefer to put it at the end so it will look like a return statement.
I personally prefer to be at the top so it would be more clear and more visible when you start reading the method logic.